# GCP Project / YouTube Data API Project Staleness Blocking?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have created a GCP project about 2 months back to be able to upload videos onto YouTube via YouTube Data API.  When we had created the project, the default quota limited the YouTube insert operations to a few videos a day so we had put in a request for a quota increase.  We were able to setup our CLI client ( https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload ) to upload videos although limited to a few.

We had waited on Google to provide an increase in Quota for our use-case for a couple months, now that the quota increase was completed, our client now gets an error message:

> "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.
> "domain": "youtube.quota",
> "reason": "quotaExceeded"

I had created new OAuth credentials and it still did not resolve the issue.

We're using this CLI

https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload

and authN via OAuth.

Does the project created "stale" because we idly waited for the quota increase and that it's now our project is blocked because of this?

How can we re-enable our ability to upload videos via these APIs?

Thanks,

-R

Comment: Did you go to google developer console and check your quota?  https://youtu.be/yuM7KH-JLu8?t=104